# How to use TA_RIGHT in SetTextAlign?

Tags: python

I want to print text to a thermal printer, and for some parts of the text I want to display at the right of the paper. In the PyCDC class there is the SetTextAlign method which can have values TA_RIGHT. Here is how I call it :

```
...
dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
dc.StartDoc(data)
dc.StartPage()

lines = data.split('|')
y = 5
for text in lines: 
    dc.TextOut(5, y, text)
    dc.SetTextAlign(TA_RIGHT|TA_TOP|TA_NOUPDATECP)
    dc.TextOut(5, y, "2")
    y = y + 200

dc.EndPage()
dc.EndDoc()
...
```

But I get error message `name 'TA_RIGHT' is not defined`
How to fix it ?

Comment: `TA_RIGHT` and those other constants are certainly not going to be globally known to Python, you will need to import them from whatever module defines them.  It looks like that module is named `win32con`.